# Illegal instruction error comes when i start asterisk 1.8.22

Tags: centos, asterisk

I have installed the asterisk 1.8.22 in centOS 32 bit.I have execute the command as below for installing asterisk:

```
./configure
make
make install
make samples
make config
```

.When i start the asterisk service then it shows like `Starting asterisk:`.But when i am starting asterisk CLI `asterisk -vvvvvvvvvr` then it shows **Illegal instruction**.I have searched about this on net but didn't get any solutions.I have installed all the dependencies for that.Can anyone help me what should i do to solve this problem to start asterisk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with less `v`?

Comment: yup but still same error come

Answer (score 9):

Very likly you are using virtualization or cpu like via-eden.

Solution:

enter in "make menuselect" -> "Compiler flags" and disable "BUILD_NATIVE"
option; then recompile Asterisk

If not help, you need edit Makefile and change architecture.

Also issue can be incorrect binary for g729 codec. So before install remove all files in /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/

Comment: I have also tried to start asterisk by disable "BUILD_NATIVE" option but still same issue comes

Comment: If i disable the "BUILD_NATIVE" option then is it affect any functionality in astrisk or not?I have installed 1.8.24 asterisk version with disable "BUILD_NATIVE" option then its work fine but when i tried to install 1.8.24 asterisk version with enable "BUILD_NATIVE" option then it was not start the asterisk.SO i want to know if i keep the  "BUILD_NATIVE" option disable then is it affect anything?

Comment: No. It not affect functionality but affect perfomance. But you have no choice probably.

Comment: Just wanted to note that this solution worked for me when building Asterisk for a Docker image, where I was having this problem after pushing to a registry, and then pulling the image and running Asterisk in another place. I needed to disable the `BUILD_NATIVE` option